# How to make an function with an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to make a function with an array in PHP. Using a library called simple_html_dom.php to extract data from a site.

I've made a piece of code that work exactly how It's suppose to but its to repetitive. So I wanted to create a function with an array.

**Here the code I'm trying to make into a function this code works**

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$pos = 0;
$food = 1;

$col_num = array();
$col_food = array();

$html = file_get_html('website');

for($i = 0;$i<220;$i+=11){

    // Extract all text from a given cell
    //insert data into the array to the field it belongs to     
    array_push($col_num, $html->find('td', $i)->plaintext);
    array_push($col_food, $html->find('td', $food)->plaintext);

            $food +=  11;
 }


 for($row = 0;$row<=19;$row++){

echo $col_num[$row].$col_food[$row]."<br>";

}
```

**Here is the code I attempted to make a function with an array**

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$pos = 0;
$food = 1;

$col_num = array();
$col_food = array();

$html = file_get_html('website');

function getcoleachrow($col = array(), $value){

   for($value=$value;$value<220;$value+=11){

    array_push($col, $html->find('td', $value)->plaintext);
   }

   for($rows = 0;$rows<=19;$rows++){

    echo $col[$rows]."<br>";
   }

}

 getcoleachrow($col_num, $num);
getcoleachrow($col_food, $food);
```

The error message I'm getting is "**Notice: Undefined variable: html**" and "**Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object**" this is on the array_push line in the function code.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with DOM, and everything to do with [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: It seems **everyone** is forgetting that you shouldn't have an optional parameter followed by a required parameter. Either switch them around or remove ` = array()`. [*Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected. Consider the following code snippet:*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $html is out of scope. You need to pass $html into the getcoleachrow function, e.g.:

```
function getcoleachrow($col = array(), $value, $html){

   for($value=$value;$value<220;$value+=11){

    array_push($col, $html->find('td', $value)->plaintext);
   }

   for($rows = 0;$rows<=19;$rows++){

    echo $col[$rows]."<br>";
   }

}

getcoleachrow($col_num, $num, $html);
```

And yes, I agree with Marc B - a good place to look for more information on the subject is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I have no idea if the rest of the function works properly, since I don't know what file_get_html() returns ;)

Comment: Glad to be of help! Could you please mark this as the answer (and up-vote if you feel like it!)?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `global $html;` inside the function...

```
function getcoleachrow($col = array(), $value){

   global $html;

   for($value=$value;$value<220;$value+=11){

    array_push($col, $html->find('td', $value)->plaintext);
   }

   for($rows = 0;$rows<=19;$rows++){

    echo $col[$rows]."<br>";
   }

}
```

Comment: Everyone always down voting using global :-)

Comment: Global var are bad practice in this case.